# Migrating an MariaDB-Database to a MySQL-Server

Tags: mysql, database, import, export, mariadb

I'm using xampp as a development suite on my pc and want to migrate a database to my webspace. There is only MySQL available.

I've tried to migrate the database with phpMyAdmin and the export/import function, but i get some errors about syntax problems. I assume, that i choose bad export-settings so the import sucks.

I didn't found any hints how to migrate my database properly. The only one solution i found says: copy your database files to the mysql-dataservice directory. But that's not possible on a normal webspace.

Have anyone some hints or a link for me, on which way i can migrate my stuff properly without generating every table and binding manually?

Thx, Ronny

Comment: Hint: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldump/

Comment: Let's see the syntax errors!!

Comment: thx for your comments, it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for your hints, i found the problem within the creation of the views in the export.

Because the dbuser on my dev-system has another name than the dbuser on my webspace (and the export enters the username of the export-user in the sql-script it creates) the export went without errors.

If i try to import this stuff, the server of my webspace don't know the dbuser of my dev system and naturally stop importing the rest. After i searched for the creation-lines of the views i changed the dbusername to a value my webspace know and now it works without any errors.

Greetings, Ronny